# XML files intermittently not loading for a c# solution

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015, vsto

EDIT: The attached screen capture shows the error returned. It is a Directory not found error. The exception details appear after the word "Message".

[image]

I wrote a C# VSTO application using Visual Studio 2015. The application runs in Microsoft Word 2013 (I am testing with Word online).

On the form load event, I run some code that opens and reads two XML files. These files contain data that I use to populate combo boxes. Each XML file has a property set with Copy Always.

The problem is the XML files do not load sometimes. If I run the code again, the XML file does load. Most of the time (80%) there are no errors and the XML files run as expected. The other times, the XML files are not loaded.

These xml files are located within the project folder with a subfolder of "xmlfiles". These files are very small at about 2k each with not more than 20 lines of elements so I would be surprised if there was a timeout issue.

Do you know why the app will load the XML files most of the time, but not all the time?

Here is the code that loads the file:

```
public void GetBookLanguages()
{
    // This application has a combobox that displays a list of languages Amazon supports.
    // the user can select from this list or enter their own.

    string xmlFile = string.Format(@"xmlfiles\\BookLanguages.xml");

    try
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        foreach (var language in xmlDoc.Descendants("item"))
        {
            string id = language.Attribute("id").Value;
            string description = language.Value;
            bookLanguages.Add(new BookLanguageTypes()
            {
                bookLangShortName = id,
                bookLangDescription = description
            });
        }

    }
    catch {
        MessageBox.Show("Warning: Could not load the BookLanguages.xml file that contains a list of " +
    "available languages. This information would normally display in a pick list. You can stil run this program.");
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Items>
  <item id="en">English (en)</item>
  <item id="de">German (de)</item>
  <item id="fr">French (fr)</item>
  <item id="it">Italian (it)</item>
  <item id="es">Spanish (es)</item>
  <item id="zh">Chinese (zh)</item>
  <item id="ja">Japanese (ja)</item>
  <item id="pt">Portuguese (pt)</item>
  <item id="ru">Russian (ru)</item>
  <item id="nl">Dutch (nl)</item>
</Items>
```

Any insight you can provide as to why these XML files do not always load would be helpful.

Comment: When it doesn't load do you get the messagebox? Why are you throwing the exception details away? Have you set a breakpoint somewhere with a condition for the file being loaded?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant to show the exception. The next time it happens I will update the question. Knew I left something out :(

Comment: Hi Ron, I finally caught the error and included it in the post. Thank you for responding earlier.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the directory as "\\mac\blah". That's a network location. Is it possible you have a disconnect between your server and wherever that network drive is?

Comment: I am running Visual Studio in a virtual machine so I guess technically it is a network path even though it is on the same machine. The VS project/solution is on a drive letter but VS clearly wants to use it in this fashion. Checking into this further, it looks like Visual Studio has a "Full Path" for the files however I cannot change that (at least using the UI). Any ideas on how to address this and move it to the proper drive letter?